# Are ㄹ게(요) and ㄹ께(요) grammatically the same ending?

Tags: verb-endings

The ㄹ게(요) construction is said to denote a promise:

> 제가 시간을 낼게요. I will make time.

However, I have seen a construction that seems to have a similar meaning, but is spelled slightly differently:

> 샤워하고 **갈께**요:) – I’ll have a shower and then come :)
>
> 앞으로 행복한 일이 많이생기도록 기도 **할께**요 - ‘I'll pray that many happy things come to pass in the future’

Are these simply alternative spellings? If so, is one incorrect? If not, what's the difference in meaning?

Comment: In fact, to be completely correct, a space is required between ㄹ and 게. I'm surprised no one caught this, because otherwise the answers are excellent. According to Dr. Ross King (http://koreangrammaticalforms.com/entry.php?eid=0000000950) and others this is a contraction of the probably future ending ㄹ 것이다 which is, of course, also written with a space.

Comment: No, -ㄹ게 is [correct](https://krdict.korean.go.kr/eng/dicSearch/SearchView?wordMatchFlag=N&ParaWordNo=80987&nation=eng&nationCode=6). 게 cannot be interpreted as 것이 here. For example, "내가 사과를 먹을게" does not equal "내가 사과를 먹을 것이."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the 네이버 국어사전, it wrote:

> 을께: "을게"의 잘못. (Incorrect form of "을게")

So, the meaning and grammatical principle of 을께 is the same as 을게.

The correct version is 을게. However people tend to emphasize their words by saying 을께, despite the fact that 을께 is wrong.

For that reason, don't use 을께 in writings, but 을게.

Answer (score 3):

'을께' is a standard pronunciation of '을게', but you should write '을게' according to 맞춤법. There is no difference in meaning and writing "을께" instead of '을게' is a common mistake Korean learners make.

There are two types of consonants, one is 'fortis (strong in Latin)' and the other is 'lenis (weak in Latin)'. Sometimes they are identified with "tense and lax".

A weak consonant such as 'ㄱ' is pronounced as a strong consonant 'ㄲ' when a certain 받침 (final consonant in a block) is used.

According to [표준발음법 (Standard Pronunciation), 제 6장 (Article 6), 27항 (Section 27)](http://www.korean.go.kr/front/page/pageView.do?page_id=P000102&mn_id=95):

> 관형사형 ‘-(으)ㄹ’ 뒤에 연결되는 ‘ㄱ, ㄷ, ㅂ, ㅅ, ㅈ’은 된소리로 발음한다.
>
> 할 것을 [할꺼슬], 갈 데가 [갈떼가], 할 바를 [할빠를], 할 수는 [할쑤는], 할 적에 [할쩌게], 갈 곳 [갈꼳], 할 도리 [할또리], 만날
>   사람 [만날싸람]
>
> 붙임] ‘-(으)ㄹ’로 시작되는 어미의 경우에도 이에 준한다.
>
> 할걸 [할껄], 할밖에 [할빠께], 할세라 [할쎄라], 할수록 [할쑤록], 할지라도 [할찌라도], 할지언정 [할찌언정], 할진대 [할찐대]

It is very important to note that some final consonants in a block could change the pronunciation that follows it. It is called "경음화 (Tensification where a weak consonant is pronounced as a strong consonant)"