# Wiki: Common spelling errors that Koreans (are likely to) make

Tags: south-korean, spelling

Those who are studying Korean could be exposed to various spelling errors made by native South Koreans. It is beneficial for language learners to know what errors are common in Korean text. Some of them have grammatical or/and spacing errors as well.

Please add your list including at least two examples per error.

Answer (score 7):

This list obeys the **standard** grammar rules promulgated by the National Institute of Korean Language (NIKL) and NIKL's Standard Korean Language Dictionary (*February 2019*). If you *disagree* with the correct spellings, please visit their website and leave your suggestions in Korean there.

A few Twitter bots ([1](https://twitter.com/Grammar_Korea), [2](https://twitter.com/hangulS2_bot), and [3](https://twitter.com/Kspell_bot)) also deal with spellings. You can find many other things there.

---

```
✘: Incorrect
✔: Correct
```

1. -ㄹ께 and -을께 [(a relevant question)](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/472/are-%E3%84%B9%EA%B2%8C%EC%9A%94-and-%E3%84%B9%EA%BB%98%EC%9A%94-grammatically-the-same-ending/475)

> - 저, 서점에 갔다 올**께**요. (✘)
> - 저, 서점에 갔다 올**게**요. (✔)
> - 나 먼저 갈**께**. (✘)
> - 나 먼저 갈**게**. (✔)
> - 남은 음식은 제가 먹을**께**요. (✘)
> - 남은 음식은 제가 먹을**게**요. (✔)
> - 이 수박은 내가 먹을**께**. (✘)
> - 이 수박은 내가 먹을**게**. (✔)

2-1. 않되, 않돼, 않 되, 않 돼, ...

> - 이 물건은 맨손으로 만지면 **않되**요. (✘)
> - 이 물건은 맨손으로 만지면 **안 돼**요. (✔)
> - 너, 그러면 **않되**. (✘)
> - 너, 그러면 **안 돼**. (✔)
> - 일이 잘 **않되**요. (✘)
> - 일이 잘 **안돼**요. (✔)
> - 어제는 공부가 **않되**서 쉬었어요. (✘)
> - 어제는 공부가 **안돼**서 쉬었어요. (✔)

2-2. 않됩니다, 않됍니다, 않 됩니다, 않 됍니다, ...

> - 잔디를 밟으시면 **않됩**니다. (✘)
> - 잔디를 밟으시면 **안 됩**니다. (✔)
> - 꽃을 꺾으시면 **않됩**니다. (✘)
> - 꽃을 꺾으시면 **안 됩**니다. (✔)

2-3. 않됬-, 않됐-, 않 됬-, 않 됐-, ...

> - 점심 먹은 지 얼마 **않됬**어요. (✘)
> - 점심 먹은 지 얼마 **안 됐**어요. (✔)
> - 우리가 그러면 **않됬**어. (✘)
> - 우리가 그러면 **안 됐**어. (✔)
> - 올해는 농사가 **않됬**어요. (✘)
> - 올해는 농사가 **안됐**어요. (✔)
> - 거참, **않됬**구먼. (✘)
> - 거참, **안됐**구먼. (✔)

3. 됬-

> - 그 환자는 어떻게 **됬**습니까? (✘)
> - 그 환자는 어떻게 **됐**습니까? (✔)
> - 다 **됬**어. (✘)
> - 다 **됐**어. (✔)

4. 어따

> - 이 전등은 **어따** 둬도 예뻐요. (✘)
> - 이 전등은 **얻다** 둬도 예뻐요. (✔)
> - **어따** 대고 반말이야? (✘)
> - **얻다** 대고 반말이야? (✔)

5. -었어서

> - 그때는 학생이**었어서** 사회를 몰랐다. (✘)
> - 그때는 학생이**어서** 사회를 몰랐다.  (✔)
> - 공부를 다섯 시간이나 **했어서** 지금 정말 졸려요. (✘)
> - 공부를 다섯 시간이나 **해서** 지금 정말 졸려요.  (✔)

6. 어떻하- (어떻해, 어떻하면, ...)

> - 운전은 **어떻해** 해? (✘)
> - 운전은 **어떻게** 해? (✔)
> - 저는 **어떻하면** 좋아요? (✘)
> - 저는 **어떡하면** 좋아요? (✔)

7. 웬지

> - 날씨가 **웬지** 수상하다. (✘)
> - 날씨가 **왠지** 수상하다. (✔)
> - 그 친구가 오늘따라 **웬지** 멋져 보인다. (✘)
> - 그 친구가 오늘따라 **왠지** 멋져 보인다. (✔)

8. 왠만하- (왠만한, 왠만하면, ...)

> - **왠만한** 사람은 모를 리 없는 일이야. (✘)
> - **웬만한** 사람은 모를 리 없는 일이야. (✔)
> - 네가 **왠만하면** 참아. (✘)
> - 네가 **웬만하면** 참아. (✔)

8. 어의없- and 어의가 없-

> - 고작 이러려고 그랬다니 정말 **어의없다**. (✘)
> - 고작 이러려고 그랬다니 정말 **어이없다**. (✔)
> - 참으로 **어의없는** 일을 겪었어. (✘)
> - 참으로 **어이없는** 일을 겪었어. (✔)
> - 그 남자는 **어의가 없다는** 듯이 웃었다. (✘)
> - 그 남자는 **어이가 없다는** 듯이 웃었다. (✔)
> - 뭐가 **어의가 없어요?** (✘)
> - 뭐가 **어이가 없어요?** (✔)

9. 낳- instead of 낫- (나아-, 나으-, ...)

   ```
   Note: 낳- is not always incorrect.
   ```

> - 병이 깨끗이 **낳았어요.** (✘)
> - 병이 깨끗이 **나았어요.** (✔)
> - 감기가 얼른 **낳으면** 좋겠어요. (✘)
> - 감기가 얼른 **나으면** 좋겠어요. (✔)

10. 걸맞는

    ```
    Note: 걸맞다 is an adjective.
    ```

> - 나는 그 여자한테 **걸맞는** 사람이야. (✘)
> - 나는 그 여자한테 **걸맞은** 사람이야. (✔)
> - 바위라고 하기에 **걸맞는** 돌이 저기에 있어! (✘)
> - 바위라고 하기에 **걸맞은** 돌이 저기에 있어! (✔)

11. 알맞는

    ```
    Note: 알맞다 is an adjective.
    ```

> - 벚꽃이 피기에 **알맞는** 날씨다. (✘)
> - 벚꽃이 피기에 **알맞은** 날씨다. (✔)
> - 걸어서 돌아다니기에 **알맞는** 거리야. (✘)
> - 걸어서 돌아다니기에 **알맞은** 거리야. (✔)

12. 맞다(-) in place of 맞는다(-)

    ```
    Note: 맞다 is a verb and its base form.
    ```

    Whether 맞다 meaning *to be correct* is a verb or adjective is a controversial issue; however, the National Institute of Korean Language (NIKL) and [우리말 배움터](http://urimal.cs.pusan.ac.kr) regard it as a verb because of its *conjugations*. Its antonym, 틀리다, is also a verb.

    Some natives would deem that 맞는다 sounds awkward claiming that "to be correct" does not relate to an action. Nonetheless, expressions such as "고장 난 시계도 하루에 두 번은 맞는다.", "오늘은 한 개 틀렸으니 내일은 다 맞자.", "풀이는 맞는데 답이 틀리면 0점이다.", and "네가 웬일로 맞는 말을 다 하는군." use 맞다 as a *verb* and also sound natural. For the latter two in particular, no Koreans use 맞은데 and 맞은 말. Therefore, 맞는다(-) is correct unless there are exceptions to the dictionary. Even [an online spell checker](http://speller.cs.pusan.ac.kr) and a word processor called 한글 say that it is *wrong* to use 맞다고 instead of 맞는다고.

    As for "맞다" and "맞아" *expressing agreement* as if they were exclamations, [Yonsei Contemporary Korean Dictionary](https://ilis.yonsei.ac.kr/dic/?keyword=%EB%A7%9E%EB%8B%A4&id=40302&order=1) mentions that *those two forms of the verb, 맞다, are used at the very beginning of a sentence* whereas, regarding such "맞다" as an ongoing usage change, NIKL have *not* accepted the specific form, "맞다", *yet*. The frequent use of "맞다" as an exclamation could be due to the catchphrase, "맞다, 게보린!", used in TV commercials for a particular pill [(a relevant article)](http://www.hani.co.kr/arti/society/schooling/445383.html).

> - 네 말이 **맞다고** 주장하는 거야? (✘)
> - 네 말이 **맞는다고** 주장하는 거야? (✔)
> - 그 주장이 **맞다면** 그자가 범인이다. (✘)
> - 그 주장이 **맞는다면** 그자가 범인이다. (✔)

13-1. 틀린 in place of 틀리는

```
    Note: 틀리다 is a verb. 틀린 is not always incorrect.
```

> - 글을 쓰다 보면 띄어쓰기를 **틀린** 일이 빈번하다. (✘)
> - 글을 쓰다 보면 띄어쓰기를 **틀리는** 일이 빈번하다. (✔)
> - 나는 정답을 **틀린** 때마다 좌절감을 느낀다. (✘)
> - 나는 정답을 **틀리는** 때마다 좌절감을 느낀다. (✔)

13-2. 틀리- in place of 다르-

```
    Note: 다르다 is an adjective.
```

A number of people mistake 다르다 (an adjective meaning *to be different*) for 틀리다 (a verb meaning *to be wrong*). Such misuse may be due to the past Japanese colonial rule and the Japanese word, ちがう. There is also a claim that it reflects well the character of the Koreans who think *being different is wrong*.

> - **틀린 그림** 찾기를 하자. (✘)
> - **다른 곳** 찾기를 하자. (✔)
> - 식물과 동물은 **틀리다**. (✘)
> - 식물과 동물은 **다르다**. (✔)
> - 너와 나는 급이 **틀려**. (✘)
> - 너와 나는 급이 **달라**. (✔)
> - 그 어려운 일을 금방 마치다니 전문가는 역시 **틀려**. (✘)
> - 그 어려운 일을 금방 마치다니 전문가는 역시 **달라**. (✔)

14. 회손

> - 명예 **회손**은 범죄이다. (✘)
> - 명예 **훼손**은 범죄이다. (✔)
> - 자연을 **회손**하지 말자. (✘)
> - 자연을 **훼손**하지 말자. (✔)

15-1. -되- instead of -대-

> - **법석되지** 말고 조용히 해라. (✘)
> - **법석대지** 말고 조용히 해라. (✔)
> - 바람이 **살랑된다.** (✘)
> - 바람이 **살랑댄다.** (✔)

15-2. -대- instead of -되-

> - 저 **세련댄** 옷차림을 봐라. (✘)
> - 저 **세련된** 옷차림을 봐라. (✔)
> - 차를 타기에는 **어중대고** 걷기에는 먼 거리였다. (✘)
> - 차를 타기에는 **어중되고** 걷기에는 먼 거리였다. (✔)

16. 맞추- in place of 맞히-

    ```
    Note: 맞추- is not always incorrect.
    ```

> - 드디어 정답을 **맞췄어요!** (✘)
> - 드디어 정답을 **맞혔어요!** (✔)
> - 과녁에 화살을 **맞추기**는 쉬워. (✘)
> - 과녁에 화살을 **맞히기**는 쉬워. (✔)

17. 밖쪽

> - 문 **밖쪽**을 내다봐라. (✘)
> - 문 **밭쪽**을 내다봐라. (✔)
> - 제 친구가 갑자기 **밖쪽**으로 달려 나갔어요. (✘)
> - 제 친구가 갑자기 **밭쪽**으로 달려 나갔어요. (✔)

18. 웅큼

> - 쌀을 손에다 한 **웅큼** 쥐어라. (✘)
> - 쌀을 손에다 한 **움큼** 쥐어라. (✔)
> - 나도 모르는 새에 머리가 한 **웅큼** 빠졌다. (✘)
> - 나도 모르는 새에 머리가 한 **움큼** 빠졌다. (✔)

19. 일각연

> - 저는 운동에 **일각연**이 있습니다. (✘)
> - 저는 운동에 **일가견**이 있습니다. (✔)
> - 전문가들은 그 주제를 두고 **일각연**을 피력하였습니다. (✘)
> - 전문가들은 그 주제를 두고 **일가견**을 피력하였습니다. (✔)

20. 갖잖-, 갇잖-, ...

> - **갖잖은** 일로 열 내지 마라. (✘)
> - **같잖은** 일로 열 내지 마라. (✔)
> - 걔 꼴이 **갖잖아서** 말도 안 나와. (✘)
> - 걔 꼴이 **같잖아서** 말도 안 나와. (✔)

21. 구렛나루

> - 어느새 **구렛나루가** 자랐어요. (✘)
> - 어느새 **구레나룻이** 자랐어요. (✔)
> - **구렛나루**도 좀 밀어 주세요. (✘)
> - **구레나룻**도 좀 밀어 주세요. (✔)

22. 역활

> - 나는 내 **역활**에 충실해야 해요. (✘)
> - 나는 내 **역할**에 충실해야 해요. (✔)
> - 할머니 **역활**을 맡을 배우가 필요해요. (✘)
> - 할머니 **역할**을 맡을 배우가 필요해요. (✔)

23-1. 숫

> - 얘는 **머리숫**이 많아. (✘)
> - 얘는 **머리숱**이 많아. (✔)
> - 고기는 **숫불**에 구워야지. (✘)
> - 고기는 **숯불**에 구워야지. (✔)

23-2. 숯

> - **숯돌**에 칼을 갈아라. (✘)
> - **숫돌**에 칼을 갈아라. (✔)
> - 나이가 들면서 **숯**이 적어졌다. (✘)
> - 나이가 들면서 **숱**이 적어졌다. (✔)

24-1. 드러내-

> - 의사가 심장을 **드러냈다.** (✘)
> - 의사가 심장을 **들어냈다.** (✔)
> - 제가 창고에서 짐을 **드러냈어요**. (✘)
> - 제가 창고에서 짐을 **들어냈어요**. (✔)

24-2. 들어내-

> - 드디어 본심을 **들어냈구먼그래.** (✘)
> - 드디어 본심을 **드러냈구먼그래.** (✔)
> - 고래가 수면 위로 머리를 **들어냈다.** (✘)
> - 고래가 수면 위로 머리를 **드러냈다.** (✔)

25. 찌게

> - 어서 **찌게**를 끓여라. (✘)
> - 어서 **찌개**를 끓여라. (✔)
> - 이 집은 김치**찌게**를 잘한대요. (✘)
> - 이 집은 김치**찌개**를 잘한대요. (✔)

26-1. 띠-, 뛰-, ... in place of 띄-

> - 걔 행동이 눈에 **띠는걸**. (✘)
> - 걔 행동이 눈에 **띄는걸**. (✔)
> - 서로 간격을 **띠어** 앉아라. (✘)
> - 서로 간격을 **띄어** 앉아라. (✔)

26-2. 띄- in place of 띠-

> - 노란빛을 **띈** 개나리가 보인다. (✘)
> - 노란빛을 **띤** 개나리가 보인다. (✔)
> - 그 남자는 허리에 총을 **띄고** 갔다. (✘)
> - 그 남자는 허리에 총을 **띠고** 갔다. (✔)

27. 몇일 and 몇 일

> - 오늘 몇 월 **몇 일**이지? (✘)
> - 오늘 몇 월 **며칠**이지? (✔)
> - **몇 일** 머무시겠습니까? (✘)
> - **며칠** 머무시겠습니까? (✔)

28. 괜찬-

> - 나는 **괜찬으니** 네가 가. (✘)
> - 나는 **괜찮으니** 네가 가. (✔)
> - 내 솜씨 어때? **괜차나**? (✘)
> - 내 솜씨 어때? **괜찮아**? (✔)

29. -벌 in place of -뻘

> - 너는 왜 나를 **자식벌** 대하듯 하니? (✘)
> - 너는 왜 나를 **자식뻘** 대하듯 하니? (✔)
> - **아버지벌** 되는 손님을 홀대하지 마라. (✘)
> - **아버지뻘** 되는 손님을 홀대하지 마라. (✔)

30. -빨 in place of -발

> - **끗빨**이 좋아야 돈을 딸 텐데. (✘)
> - **끗발**이 좋아야 돈을 딸 텐데. (✔)
> - **화장빨** 때문인지 사진이 잘 나왔어. (✘)
> - **화장발** 때문인지 사진이 잘 나왔어. (✔)

31. 궂이

> - 그 가게에 **궂이** 가야겠어? (✘)
> - 그 가게에 **굳이** 가야겠어? (✔)
> - 주인공은 눈을 **궂이** 감고 고통을 참았다. (✘)
> - 주인공은 눈을 **굳이** 감고 고통을 참았다. (✔)

32. 바래- in place of 바라-

    ```
    Note: 바라다 (to want, hope, ...) is a regular verb.
    ```

    Whether certain forms such as 바래, 바램, 바랬어, and 바래요 are correct is a controversial issue; however, NIKL regard them as wrong [based on *etymological evidence*](https://www.korean.go.kr/front/onlineQna/onlineQnaView.do?mn_id=216&qna_seq=70698). Those incorrect usages are widespread now and a lot of people prefer to use 바래- instead of 바라-. An interesting point is that some Koreans use 바라- in written language but 바래- in spoken language. This "what I write is not what I say" attitude can also be found in the cases of 네 and 니, and 나무라- and 나무래-.

    Despite the current situation, it will be too difficult for NIKL to accept 바래- as correct; accepting those usages will add complexity to the current rules. On top of that, some people would oppose the idea of making both 바라다 and 바래다 standard words to mean *to want, hope, ...* because there is 바래다 (to discolor).

> - 대학에 합격하기를 **바래**. (✘)
> - 대학에 합격하기를 **바라**. (✔)
> - 내 **바램**대로 모레는 바람이 덜 불었으면 좋겠다. (✘)
> - 내 **바람**대로 모레는 바람이 덜 불었으면 좋겠다. (✔)
> - 난 네가 행복하게 살기를 **바랬어**. (✘)
> - 난 네가 행복하게 살기를 **바랐어**. (✔)
> - 아니, 뭘 또 **바래요**? (✘)
> - 아니, 뭘 또 **바라요**? (✔)

33. 나무래- in place of 나무라-

> - 누가 누구를 **나무래**? (✘)
> - 누가 누구를 **나무라**? (✔)
> - 이 작품은 **나무랠** 데가 없다. (✘)
> - 이 작품은 **나무랄** 데가 없다. (✔)

34. 놀래- in place of 놀라-

    ```
    Note: 놀래다 is (1) a dialect (non-standard) word for 놀라다 and (2) a causative form of 놀라다.
    ```

> - 네 소식에 깜짝 **놀랬어**. (✘)
> - 네 소식에 깜짝 **놀랐어**. (✔)
> - 내 횡격막이 **놀랬는지** 딸꾹질이 난다. (✘)
> - 내 횡격막이 **놀랐는지** 딸꾹질이 난다. (✔)

35-1. 니 in place of 네

> - **니**가 잘하는 일을 해 봐. (✘)
> - **네**가 잘하는 일을 해 봐. (✔)
> - **니** 친구가 그러디? (✘)
> - **네** 친구가 그러디? (✔)

35-2. 너 in place of 네

> - **너**가 자꾸 생각나. (✘)
> - **네**가 자꾸 생각나. (✔)
> - 이 책은 **너** 거 맞지? (✘)
> - 이 책은 **네** 거 맞지? (✔)

36. 새- and 세- in place of 새우-

    ```
    Note: 밤새다 is different in meaning from 밤새우다.
    ```

> - 책을 읽느라고 밤을 **샜어**. (✘)
> - 책을 읽느라고 밤을 **새웠어**. (✔)
> - 밤**세면서** 일하면 건강에 안 좋아요. (✘)
> - 밤**새우면서** 일하면 건강에 안 좋아요. (✔)

37. 피- in place of 피우-

    ```
    Note: 피우다 is the causative form of 피다.
    ```

> - 딴청 **피지** 말고 일 좀 해. (✘)
> - 딴청 **피우지** 말고 일 좀 해. (✔)
> - 그건 호랑이 담배 **필** 적 일이에요. (✘)
> - 그건 호랑이 담배 **피울** 적 일이에요. (✔)

38. 바껴- in place of 바뀌어-

    ```
    Note: 바끼다 is a dialect word for 바뀌다.
    ```

> - 이 집 실내 장식이 완전히 **바꼈군요**. (✘)
> - 이 집 실내 장식이 완전히 **바뀌었군요**. (✔)
> - 그 규칙은 자주 **바껴**. (✘)
> - 그 규칙은 자주 **바뀌어**. (✔)

39-1. -율 in place of -률

> - **성공율**이 높은 수술을 받아라. (✘)
> - **성공률**이 높은 수술을 받아라. (✔)
> - 우리 회사에서는 **이직율**을 낮추려고 노력하더라. (✘)
> - 우리 회사에서는 **이직률**을 낮추려고 노력하더라. (✔)

39-2. -률 in place of -율

> - 요즘에는 **환률** 변동이 크네. (✘)
> - 요즘에는 **환율** 변동이 크네. (✔)
> - **전률**이 느껴지지 않니? (✘)
> - **전율**이 느껴지지 않니? (✔)

40-1. 뵈- in place of 봬- (뵈어-)

> - 저는 내일 어르신을 **뵈요**. (✘)
> - 저는 내일 어르신을 **봬요**. (✔)
> - 저기 산이 **뵈**. (✘)
> - 저기 산이 **봬**. (✔)

40-2. 봬- in place of 뵈-

> - 저는 강이 **봬는** 집에 살아요. (✘)
> - 저는 강이 **뵈는** 집에 살아요. (✔)
> - 내가 정말 착해 **봬냐**? (✘)
> - 내가 정말 착해 **뵈냐**? (✔)

41. 오랫만

> - **오랫만**이야. (✘)
> - **오랜만**이야. (✔)
> - **오랫만**에 등산해서 다리가 아파요. (✘)
> - **오랜만**에 등산해서 다리가 아파요. (✔)

42-1. 붙이- in place of 부치-

> - 이 편지를 회사로 **붙여** 줘. (✘)
> - 이 편지를 회사로 **부쳐** 줘. (✔)
> - 이번 일은 비밀에 **붙이게**. (✘)
> - 이번 일은 비밀에 **부치게**. (✔)

42-2. 부치- in place of 붙이-

> - 이 봉투에 우표를 **부쳐**. (✘)
> - 이 봉투에 우표를 **붙여**. (✔)
> - 공부에 흥미를 **부쳐** 봐. (✘)
> - 공부에 흥미를 **붙여** 봐. (✔)

43-1. 연예 in place of 연애

> - 너는 사내 **연예** 해 봤어? (✘)
> - 너는 사내 **연애** 해 봤어? (✔)
> - 아직 **연예** 한 번 못 했어요. (✘)
> - 아직 **연애** 한 번 못 했어요. (✔)

43-2. 연애 in place of 연예

> - 저 **연애**인이 그렇게 유명해? (✘)
> - 저 **연예**인이 그렇게 유명해? (✔)
> - 그 가수가 **연애** 활동을 중단하겠다고 했다며? (✘)
> - 그 가수가 **연예** 활동을 중단하겠다고 했다며? (✔)

44-1. -든 in place of -던

> - **가든** 길 계속 가. (✘)
> - **가던** 길 계속 가. (✔)
> - 그 사람은 잘 **있든**? (✘)
> - 그 사람은 잘 **있던**? (✔)

44-2. -던(-) in place of -든(-)

> - **가던 말던** 맘대로 해. (✘)
> - **가든 말든** 맘대로 해. (✔)
> - 어디에 **있던** 나를 잊지 마. (✘)
> - 어디에 **있든** 나를 잊지 마. (✔)
> - 내가 글을 **쓰던**지 그림을 **그리던**지 해야지, 원! (✘)
> - 내가 글을 **쓰든**지 그림을 **그리든**지 해야지, 원! (✔)

45-1. 반듯이 in place of 반드시

> - 저는 제가 한 일에 책임을 **반듯이** 지겠습니다. (✘)
> - 저는 제가 한 일에 책임을 **반드시** 지겠습니다. (✔)
> - **반듯이** 제때 와라. (✘)
> - **반드시** 제때 와라. (✔)
> - 저는 **반듯이** 살아서 돌아가겠습니다. (✘)
> - 저는 **반드시** 살아서 돌아가겠습니다. (✔)

45-2. 반드시 in place of 반듯이

> - 고개를 **반드시** 들고 제 눈을 보세요. (✘)
> - 고개를 **반듯이** 들고 제 눈을 보세요. (✔)
> - 나는 비뚤어지지 않고 **반드시** 살겠어. (✘)
> - 나는 비뚤어지지 않고 **반듯이** 살겠어. (✔)

46. 힘듬

> - 삶이 힘들면 그 **힘듬**을 즐길 줄 아는 사람이 되자. (✘)
> - 삶이 힘들면 그 **힘듦**을 즐길 줄 아는 사람이 되자. (✔)
> - 그 환자는 숨을 쉬기 **힘듬**에도 정신을 잃지 않으려고 하였다. (✘)
> - 그 환자는 숨을 쉬기 **힘듦**에도 정신을 잃지 않으려고 하였다. (✔)

47. 팜 in place of 팖

> - 이곳에서는 사고**팜**이 자유롭다. (✘)
> - 이곳에서는 사고**팖**이 자유롭다. (✔)
> - 분양은 토지나 건물 따위를 나누어 **팜**을 의미한다. (✘)
> - 분양은 토지나 건물 따위를 나누어 **팖**을 의미한다. (✔)

48. -녜

> - 걔가 나보고 자기 옷이 괜찮아 보이**녜**. (✘)
> - 걔가 나보고 자기 옷이 괜찮아 보이**냬**. (✔)
> - 친구들이 너 언제 오**녜**. (✘)
> - 친구들이 너 언제 오**냬**. (✔)

49. -쟤

> - 걔가 나보고 자기랑 거기 같이 가**쟤**. (✘)
> - 걔가 나보고 자기랑 거기 같이 가**재**. (✔)
> - 친구들이 축구 이제 그만하**쟤**. (✘)
> - 친구들이 축구 이제 그만하**재**. (✔)

50. 계시다(-) in place of 계신다(-)

> - 이 방송을 듣고 **계시다**면 밖으로 나가시기 바랍니다. (✘)
> - 이 방송을 듣고 **계신다**면 밖으로 나가시기 바랍니다. (✔)
> - 오늘 선생님은 댁에 **계시다**. (✘)
> - 오늘 선생님은 댁에 **계신다**. (✔)

51. 아는 척 in place of 알은척

> - 그때 왜 나를 보고 **아는 척**도 안 했어? (✘)
> - 그때 왜 나를 보고 **알은척**도 안 했어? (✔)
> - 쟤는 내 푸념을 한참 듣고서야 **아는 척**하더라. (✘)
> - 쟤는 내 푸념을 한참 듣고서야 **알은척**하더라. (✔)

52. -스런 in place of -스러운

> - 아동이 또래 말을 따라 하는 것은 **자연스런** 일이다. (✘)
> - 아동이 또래 말을 따라 하는 것은 **자연스러운** 일이다. (✔)
> - 제게는 **사랑스런** 아이가 있습니다. (✘)
> - 제게는 **사랑스러운** 아이가 있습니다. (✔)

53. 본따(-)

> - 남의 소설을 **본따** 쓴 글은 가치가 없어. (✘)
> - 남의 소설을 **본떠** 쓴 글은 가치가 없어. (✔)
> - 아이는 부모 언행을 **본따게** 마련이지. (✘)
> - 아이는 부모 언행을 **본뜨게** 마련이지. (✔)

54. 엄한 in place of 애먼 and 앰한

> - 괜히 **엄한** 사람 잡으려고 날뛰지 마라. (✘)
> - 괜히 **앰한** 사람 잡으려고 날뛰지 마라. (✔)
> - 괜히 **애먼** 사람 잡으려고 날뛰지 마라. (✔)
> - 서둘러 할 일은 안 하고 **엄한** 일 붙들고 있느냐? (✘)
> - 서둘러 할 일은 안 하고 **애먼** 일 붙들고 있느냐? (✔)

55. 담구-

> - 계곡물에 수박을 **담구고** 기다려. (✘)
> - 계곡물에 수박을 **담그고** 기다려. (✔)
> - 내일 김치를 **담궈서** 이웃에게 나누어 줄 계획이야. (✘)
> - 내일 김치를 **담가서** 이웃에게 나누어 줄 계획이야. (✔)

56. 잠구-

> - 나는 문을 **잠구고** 숨을 죽였다. (✘)
> - 나는 문을 **잠그고** 숨을 죽였다. (✔)
> - 그 입을 **잠궈**. (✘)
> - 그 입을 **잠가**. (✔)

57. 치루-

> - 학교에서 힘든 시험을 **치루고** 집에 가서 쉬었어요. (✘)
> - 학교에서 힘든 시험을 **치르고** 집에 가서 쉬었어요. (✔)
> - 물건값을 제때 **치뤄야지**. (✘)
> - 물건값을 제때 **치러야지**. (✔)

58-1. 벌리- in place of 벌이-

> - 일을 **벌려도** 너무 크게 **벌렸어**. (✘)
> - 일을 **벌여도** 너무 크게 **벌였어**. (✔)
> - 어제 여기서 학생 둘이 입씨름을 **벌렸어요**. (✘)
> - 어제 여기서 학생 둘이 입씨름을 **벌였어요**. (✔)

58-2. 벌이- in place of 벌리-

> - 그게 돈이 잘 **벌이는** 일이니? (✘)
> - 그게 돈이 잘 **벌리는** 일이니? (✔)
> - 둘이 얼마간 간격을 **벌이고** 섰네. (✘)
> - 둘이 얼마간 간격을 **벌리고** 섰네. (✔)

59. 바라- in place of 발라-

> - 그 사람은 예의가 **바라**. (✘)
> - 그 사람은 예의가 **발라**. (✔)
> - 얘는 행실이 **바라요**. (✘)
> - 얘는 행실이 **발라요**. (✔)

60. 대따

> - 그럴 때에는 **대따** 뛰면 돼. (✘)
> - 그럴 때에는 **딥다** 뛰면 돼. (✔)
> - 바닷가로 피서 갔다가 **대따** 고생만 했어요. (✘)
> - 바닷가로 피서 갔다가 **딥다** 고생만 했어요. (✔)

61. 되려

> - 잘못한 사람이 **되려** 큰소리를 치는구먼. (✘)
> - 잘못한 사람이 **되레** 큰소리를 치는구먼. (✔)
> - 늦게 출발한 것이 **되려** 잘한 일이었다. (✘)
> - 늦게 출발한 것이 **되레** 잘한 일이었다. (✔)

62. 들려- and 들리- in place of 들러- and 들르- respectively

> - 친구 집에 **들렸다가** 갈게요. (✘)
> - 친구 집에 **들렀다가** 갈게요. (✔)
> - 여기는 일전에 내가 **들린** 곳이야. (✘)
> - 여기는 일전에 내가 **들른** 곳이야. (✔)

63. -ㄹ려면, -ㄹ려고, and -ㄹ래야 in place of -려면, -려고, and -려야 respectively

> - 이거 **먹을려면** 먹어. (✘)
> - 이거 **먹으려면** 먹어. (✔)
> - 이 시간에 영화 보러 **갈려고**요? (✘)
> - 이 시간에 영화 보러 **가려고**요? (✔)
> - 걔는 내가 **미워할래야** 미워할 수 없는 인물이야. (✘)
> - 걔는 내가 **미워하려야** 미워할 수 없는 인물이야. (✔)

64. 빌어(-) in place of 빌려(-)

> - 이 자리를 **빌어** 감사하다는 말씀을 드리고 싶습니다. (✘)
> - 이 자리를 **빌려** 감사하다는 말씀을 드리고 싶습니다. (✔)
> - 그 사람은 술김을 **빌어서** 하고 싶었던 말을 했다. (✘)
> - 그 사람은 술김을 **빌려서** 하고 싶었던 말을 했다. (✔)

65. 멀지 in place of 머지

    ```
    Note: 머지않다 relates to time.
    ```

> - **멀지 않아** 진실이 밝혀지겠죠. (✘)
> - **머지않아** 진실이 밝혀지겠죠. (✔)
> - 이제 겨울이 **멀지 않았다**. (✘)
> - 이제 겨울이 **머지않았다**. (✔)

66. 땡기-

> - 종일 걸었더니 종아리가 **땡긴다**. (✘)
> - 종일 걸었더니 종아리가 **땅긴다**. (✔)
> - 그 음식 사진을 보니 입맛이 **땡긴다**. (✘)
> - 그 음식 사진을 보니 입맛이 **당긴다**. (✔)

67. 넘어 in place of 너머

> - 저 산 **넘어**에는 집이 한 채 있다. (✘)
> - 저 산 **너머**에는 집이 한 채 있다. (✔)
> - 네가 어깨**넘어**로 배운 기술을 쓸 시간이야. (✘)
> - 네가 어깨**너머**로 배운 기술을 쓸 시간이야. (✔)

Comment: I agree with most of them (well, it's hard to argue in the matter of *spelling* which is ultimately decided by someone), but I have to disagree with 맞다 (12).  In my life I've *never* seen anyone using "맞는다" to mean anything other than "(You) will get hit/beaten."  In my opinion, 맞다(to be correct) is no longer a verb, nor an adjective, but something in between, and if traditional grammar cannot explain this exception then it's a problem for the grammarians, not native speakers.

Comment: @jick That can be explained as native speakers [do not really care about grammar](http://legacy.www.hani.co.kr/section-009000000/2003/06/009000000200306041903200.html). Even a [1984 news article](https://newslibrary.naver.com/viewer/index.nhn?articleId=1984062500329211023&editNo=2&printCount=1&publishDate=1984-06-25&officeId=00032&pageNo=11&printNo=11920&publishType=00020) used "맞는다" to mean "is correct." Your own experience cannot deny the fact that some people have used "맞는다."

Comment: To be more specific, some [do not differentiate 동사 (verbs) from 형용사 (adjectives)](http://www.hani.co.kr/arti/society/schooling/252544.html) regarding several words. For example, 웃기다 should be used as in 이것 참 웃기는 일이다 but I have heard 이것 참 웃긴 일이다 from some speakers, which means that -는 is regarded as -ㄴ by them. I could be wrong, but I guess other reasons are that "네 답이 맞다" (of course, 맞다 as the *base* form) was once provided as a dictionary example and that most natives have been influenced by English ("correct" is an adjective) and translations.

Comment: I keep saying, "native speakers do not care about grammar" is an oxymoron. In linguistics, grammar is what native speakers do, by definition. The textbooks, dissertations, and news articles discussing the grammar is but a reflection of an actual grammar, which is "how native speakers speak the language". We do a disservice to Korean learners by teaching them expressions virtually unused, just because textbook writers were too lazy to follow up on actual linguistic change.

Comment: Besides, if you want, I can also find usages - this example dates back to 1938. https://newslibrary.naver.com/viewer/index.nhn?articleId=1938071600209204009&editNo=2&printCount=1&publishDate=1938-07-16&officeId=00020&pageNo=4&printNo=6068&publishType=00020 "맞다마자 물이 문어진대로쏟아지고 이리둔 나려오질 안는게야"

Comment: @jick If you need the accurate term, I am always referring to the *prescriptive* grammar, but I said *not really* not *not*. Anyway, 맞는다 was also used in 1936 ("내꿈은대개맞는다"). In addition, I do not believe that it is the right claim that 맞는다 is "virtually unused" if you meant virtually as *almost*, because there are a number of examples. The grammatical correctness for Korean cannot be judged by one's preference. As a child, I was taught that [맞춤법 and relevant rules are 법(法, laws)](http://legalinsight.co.kr/archives/37842). There might be a time when 맞다고 will also be considered correct, though.

Comment: I think it is of no use to discuss the current rules here, since nothing can change here. On the Web, there are similar debates about 틀리다 and 바라다 as well. It is better to keep asking the NIKL to revise or make exceptions to the rules. I will just abide by the rules *valid at the moment*.